# System protection disk space keeps being reset to 100%

Tags: windows-10, disk-space

When I find myself running out of disk space sometimes my `System Volume Information` folder is huge. So I open `System Protection`, go to my Windows drive and find that `Disk Space Usage` is set to 100%. I change it to around 20%, but it seems to go back to 100% automatically after a while. Anyone know what could be changing it back to 100%, or how can I diagnose this behavior?

[image]

Comment: There are numerous threads on the Microsoft support forums about this issue, with zero help provided by anyone. This indicates to me that it may just be a bug in Windows. You could try running the command line program, e.g., `vssadmin resize shadowstorage /for=C: /on=C: /maxsize=3%` in an elevated prompt, but likely this will not solve the issue.

Comment: @LayneBernardo I added a daily scheduled task for that command, which should be enough to keep the disk space under control, thanks!